# Login in Codeigniter display the current user details after successful login

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:

```
 public function view()
        {
        $seid=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['result']=$this->search_model->getall($seid);
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
        }
```

model:

```
public function getall($seid)
{
    $this->db->select('uid','name','details','img');
    $this->db->where("email",$seid);
     $q=$this->db->get('tbl_reg');
    return $q->result();
}
```

view:

```
<?php foreach($result as $row){?>
<?php <?php   echo "username:".$row['name'];die();?> 

<br/>
<?php echo "email:" .$row['email'];?>
<br/>
<?php echo "user id:" .$row['uid'];?>
<?php echo "Details:".$row['details'];?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['img'] ;}?>"  style="width:104px;height:142px"; />
```

when i logged in  to  the home page , did not display the current logged in user details.  what  is the problem with this code .Please provide solution for this problem?

Comment: In your model you are using `return $q->result();`, therefore the result set is in "array of objects", which means you have to use this `$row->name` instead of this `$row['name']` to obtain your data in your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get single row from database please use `$q->row_object()` or `$q->row_array()`. Then you don't need to use foreach on view. Please see below example:-

Your Modal

```
public function getall($seid)
{
    $this->db->select('uid','name','details','img');
    $this->db->where("email",$seid);
    $q=$this->db->get('tbl_reg');
    return $q->row_array();
}
```

On your View

```
<?php   echo "username:".$row['name']; ?> 
<br/>
<?php echo "email:" .$row['email'];?>
<br/>
<?php echo "user id:" .$row['uid'];?>
<?php echo "Details:".$row['details'];?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['img'] ;?>"  style="width:104px;height:142px"; />
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your model to use the following:

```
public function getall($seid)
{
    $this->db->select('uid','name','details','img');
    $this->db->where("email",$seid);
    $q=$this->db->get('tbl_reg');

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

Comment: why would this work? you need to provide an explanation

Comment: in views , you have used result as array but in your model, you return an object and hence either you need to change your views to get echo that variable as object or change your model to give result as array as given in my model.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, add the user details in the following manner,

```
public function view()
    {
    $seid=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data['result']=$this->search_model->getall($seid);
    $newdata = array(
               'username'  => <USERNAME>,
               'email'     => <MAILID>,
                ...........
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
    $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: You want to store username just add it. otherwise remove it. in this array ($newdata), like an example code.